# SQL Injection and Laravel

Tags: database, laravel, code-injection

I was recently reading about SQL Injections and I'd like to know if a code like this is prone to be injected with bad queries.

```
DB::table($table)->select('*')->where('nome', 'LIKE', '%' . $_GET['search'] . '%')->get()
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: No, it's not.`$_GET['search']` will be escaped if you are using the `where()` function. You should still validate user input whenever possible but the only times you need to worry about SQL injection is when using the raw functions. (`DB::raw()`, `selectRaw()`, `whereRaw()`, `groupByRaw()` and `havingRaw`). And even then, those functions provide ways to escape the user input.

Comment: @IGP I believe the variables are actually turned into prepared statements, which is different from escaping and even more secure.

Comment: They are. I just didn't think it was different.

Comment: Thank, guys, it really helped me.